# how to train and deploy YOLOv5 on aws sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, yolov5

I want to train YOLOv5 on aws sagemaker also deploy the model on sagemaker itself,need to know about entrypoint python script as well. how can I build a pipeline for this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This official AWS [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/speed-up-yolov4-inference-to-twice-as-fast-on-amazon-sagemaker/) has information on how to deploy YOLOv4. I wonder if you can use it as a guide and change the model to v5.

If not, there is a 3rd party implementation of YOLOv5 [here](https://github.com/HKT-SSA/yolov5-on-sagemaker).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the YoloV5 on SageMaker and MLOps using Step Functions [here](https://github.com/Napkin-DL/rapid-mlops-poc).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to link below. It has some example notebooks you can use to train the model on Sagemaker jupyter notebook.

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-train-and-deploy-yolov5